# how to put html code into php code for reading PDF file?

Tags: php

i am trying to add html tag in php code which is used for reading PDF File.i want to add link bottom of the page and above this link pdf file is display.but i can't find way to do this. 
i would like to do something like this image..
[image]

means i want inline scroller for PDF file dispaly and then link for other pdf files.

here the my code:

```
<?php
$filename=base64_decode($_REQUEST['file2']);
$new_id=base64_decode($_REQUEST['id2']);
$line = "<html>";
$line .= "<head>";
$line .= "<title>PDF test</title>";
$line .= "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>";
$line .= "</head>";
$line .= "<body><div style='position:absolute; overflow:scroll;height:100px !important'>";
$file = WEB_ROOT."/admin/images/plastic_sandesh/pdffile/".$filename;
$length = filesize($file);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$file);
header("Content-Length: ".$length); 
@readfile($file);

$line .= "</div></body>";
$line .= "</html>";
?>

<iframe style='border:1px solid #FEFEFE; width:100px; height:100px;'>
<div style="position:absolute; overflow:scroll;height:100px !important">
<?php
$Qry2 =mysql_query( "select * from `tbl_plasticsandesh_pages` where `sandesh_id`='$new_id' order by `order`") or die(mysql_error());
$j=1;
 $cnt=mysql_num_rows($Qry2);
while($res2 = mysql_fetch_array($Qry2))
{
    $file_name2=base64_encode($res['pdf_page']);
    ?>
  <a href="readpdf.php?act=view&file=<?php echo $file_name2;?>$id2=<?php echo $_REQUEST['id2'];?>" style="color:#111"><?php echo $j;?></a><br />
<?php
$j++;
}
?>
 </div>
 </iframe>
```

but the problem is the only pdf file is display ,no link for other PDF files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is solved by using this:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo SITE_URL."/admin/images/plastic_sandesh/pdffile/".$filename;?>" height="100%" width="100%">
<html>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38);">
<embed width="100%" height="" name="plugin" src="<?php echo SITE_URL."/admin/images/plastic_sandesh/pdffile/".$filename;?>" type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

and then another code for links and its work.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting headers and browser displays your page as application/pdf. That's why it doesn't show links.

Solution: display page as html page and show pdf on it in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have got my answer.